# get request URL in webhook woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to get te request_url from the shop who use my webhook, actually I have this code:

```
$webhookContent=        "";
$webhook=               fopen('php://input' , 'rb');
while (!feof($webhook)) {
    $webhookContent .=  fread($webhook, 4096);
}
fclose($webhook);
$data=      json_decode($webhookContent,true);

$shop = $json['Shop'];
```

But, since wordpress update their versions, I can`t get The URL where the webhook was delivered, is very important to get it, because I provide a logistic service based in this URL.

In the webhook content only have the details of the order (I use woocommerce)

Update:

I can solved my problem usign only this:
`$_SERVER['HTTP_X_WC_WEBHOOK_SOURCE']`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you has to get the data in raw, i did it using this:
        $postdata = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));